# The content of my tooltip is not formatted in html

Tags: jquery, jquery-tooltip

I'm interested to make accessible tooltips with tooltipster. The problem is that the content of my tooltip is not formatted in html. it's almost ok , except the contents of the tooltip that does not support html tags (p and img ). The function .html() should do the job, no ?

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="my_id" class="picto-tooltip" aria-describedby="my_id_description"></a>
<div id="my_id_description" role="tooltip">
<p>This the title for the tooltip</p>
<img src="/images/myimage.jpg" alt="Alternative text for the image" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
    $('#my_id').tooltipster({
    functionInit: function(){
    return $('#my_id_description').html();
    },
    functionReady: function(){
    $('#my_id_description').attr('aria-hidden', false);
    },
    functionAfter: function(){
    $('#my_id_description').attr('aria-hidden', true);
    }
    });
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Read step 4 at http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#demos

Comment: Yes it works this way, but I have to do it in another way to make it keyboard accessible. The method is on the same page of your link, at the bottom. This section is called "Make tooltips accessible to persons with disabilities".

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, it sounds like the content of the tooltip has to be a jQuery element and you're using a string.

Try returning the element instead of the HTML of the element:

```
$('#my_id').tooltipster({
  functionInit: function(){
    return $('#my_id_description');
  },
  ...
});
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this either, but in this case the tooltip content is empty.

Comment: Thank tou Carlos. I know it works when html is generated with js. But for keyboard accessibility I need to get the tooltip content (p and img) inside the html

Comment: I got the answer : just wrap the sting in another "$())", like this : return $($('#my_id_description').html());